# Making member-only websites

Tags: wordpress, civimember, user-account

We are a small charity using CiviCRM with WordPress.

I had a look at existing question [Member only page-login using civicrm database](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14370/) , but the answer does not address our scenario, i.e. how to integrate members-only login for contacts from CiviCRM and users from WP.

We want to provide some pages for members only.

Comment: Does this old forum post help you? https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32502.0

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin on one of me other sites but it should work on a site with Civi too. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-members-only/

In the plugin settings, you can set the login page and you can whitelist urls on your site that are open to the public.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) plugin.  This will allow you to sync a CiviCRM Membership or Group with a WordPress role or capability.

Once you've done this, you'll need a second WordPress plugin to restrict pages by role.  [There are several WordPress plugins](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-wordpress-pages-by-user-role/) to accomplish this; which one works best for your situation may vary.